# Difference between holomorphic and $\mathbb{C}$ differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm studying complex numbers and I have to do some exercises about derivatives of complex function, any of them ask to find the points where a function is  $\mathbb{C}$ differentiable and if $f$ is holomorphic at these points, but I really can't help in the second part.

I'm checking the differentiable region of $f$ using the Cauchy-Riemann equations because there is a theorem that says if $f$ satisfies the equations then it is differentiable at these points but if $f$ satisfies theses equation is not $f$ holomorphic in a open neighborhood of these points? I'm really confused about these definition.

Comment: holomorphic around $z=a$ means complex differentiable on an open  set $U$ containing $a$, for example on the disk $\{z \in \mathbb{C}, |z-a| < r\}$, i.e. complex differentiable at every point of $U$ : for every $z_0 \in U$ and as $z \to z_0$ : $f(z) = f(z_0) + (z-z_0)g(z_0)+o(|z-z_0|)$. When $f(z)$ is holomorphic, this function $g(z)$ deserves to be called $f'(z)$

Comment: so holomorphic at only one point doesn't exist, neither does analytic at only one point